# Spark: create a sessionId based on timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I like to do the following transformation. Given a data frame that records whether a user is logged. My aim is to create a sessionId for each record based on the timestamp and a pre-defined value TIMEOUT = 20.

**A session period is defined as : [first record --> first record + Timeout]**

For instance, the original DataFrame would look like the following:

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(List(
  ("user1",0),
  ("user1",3),
  ("user1",15),
  ("user1",22),
  ("user1",28),
  ("user1",41),
  ("user1",45),
  ("user1",85),
  ("user1",90)
)).toDF("user_id","timestamp")
```

df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [user_id: string, timestamp: int]

```
+-------+---------+
|user_id|timestamp|
+-------+---------+
|user1  |0        |
|user1  |3        |
|user1  |15       |
|user1  |22       |
|user1  |28       |
|user1  |41       |
|user1  |45       |
|user1  |85       |
|user1  |90       |
+-------+---------+
```

The goal is:

```
+-------+---------+----------+
|user_id|timestamp|session_id|
+-------+---------+----------+
|user1  |0        |   0      |-> first record (session 0: period [0->20])
|user1  |3        |   0      |
|user1  |15       |   0      |
|user1  |22       |   1      |-> 22 not in [0->20]->new session(period 22->42)
|user1  |28       |   1      |
|user1  |41       |   1      |
|user1  |45       |   2      |-> 45 not in [22->42]->newsession(period 45->65)
|user1  |85       |   3      |
|user1  |90       |   3      |
+-------+---------+----------+
```

Are there any elegant solution to solve this problem, preferably in Scala.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is probably a cheap trick but have you tried `df.withColumn("session_id", floor($"timestamp"/20) )
`

Comment: @philantrovert I believe that if the OP uses real timestamps, it won't work. (The example is cheap and misleading in this case).

Comment: Yes, so is my comment. :D

Comment: @philantrovert your solution gives a fixed session periods ( _session1_ [0;20] ; _session1_ [20;40]  ...). This doesn't match with my case.

Comment: @NGI doing this with a timeout isn't possible

Comment: Thx @eliasah :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an elegant solution but this worked for given data format.

```
sc.parallelize(List(
      ("user1", 0),
      ("user1", 3),
      ("user1", 15),
      ("user1", 22),
      ("user1", 28),
      ("user1", 41),
      ("user1", 45),
      ("user1", 85),
      ("user1", 90))).toDF("user_id", "timestamp").map { x =>
      val userId = x.getAs[String]("user_id")
      val timestamp = x.getAs[Int]("timestamp")
      val session = timestamp / 20
      (userId, timestamp, session)
    }.toDF("user_id", "timestamp", "session").show()
```

**Result**

[image]

You can change `timestamp / 20` according to your need.

Comment: Thanks but how can I get the session start timestamp as  mentionned in my example above.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my code.
Two issues here:
1,I think the performance is not well.
2,I use the "userid" to join, if this doesn't meet your requirement. You add a new column with a same value to timeSetFrame and newSessionSec.

```
var newSession = ss.sparkContext.parallelize(List(
  ("user1", 0),      ("user1", 3),      ("user1", 15),      ("user1", 22),
  ("user1", 28),      ("user1", 41),      ("user1", 45),      ("user1", 85),
  ("user1", 90))).zipWithIndex().toDF("tmp", "index")

val getUser_id = udf( ( s : Row) => {
  s.getString(0)
})

val gettimestamp = udf( (  s : Row) => {
  s.getInt(1)
})
val newSessionSec = newSession.withColumn( "user_id", getUser_id($"tmp"))
  .withColumn( "timestamp", gettimestamp($"tmp")).drop( "tmp")  //.show()

val timeSet : Array[Int] = newSessionSec.select("timestamp").collect().map( s=>s.getInt(0))
val timeSetFrame = ss.sparkContext.parallelize( Seq(( "user1",timeSet))).toDF( "user_id", "tset")
val newSessionThird = newSessionSec.join( timeSetFrame, Seq("user_id"), "outer")  // .show

val getSessionID = udf( ( ts: Int, aa: Seq[Int]) => {
  var result = 0
  var begin = 0
  val loop = new Breaks
  loop.breakable {
    for (time <- aa) {
      if (time > (begin + 20)) {
        begin = time
        result += 1
      }
      if (time == ts) {
        loop.break;
      }
    }
  }
  result
})
newSessionThird.withColumn( "sessionID", getSessionID( $"timestamp", $"tset")).drop("tset", "index").show()
```